# Google Rich Snippets working for one author but not the other

Tags: html, seo, google-plus, rich-snippets

I'm using the Rich Snippets with two of my websites.

http://www.meow.fr

http://www.haikyo.org

They both have the same two authors: Jordy and Jing. What is amazing is that the Google+ photo show for Jing but not for Jordy (which is me). I have NO CLUE why, it's beyond my understanding. And Jing is lucky because she didn't set a thing ;)

Please check this Google result:

https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ameow.fr#q=site%3Ameow.fr+Japan&hl=en&prmd=imvns&ei=vBw_T6HdBK-wiQe-7ZDhBA&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=5ee9902973786e59&biw=1205&bih=724

Check the first page, the second, the third... basically, she has a badge for all her articles, but there are none for mine.

I have no idea what to check, everything seems to be in order. There could be something wrong with my Google+ account but what? I don't know. Google is full of mysteries.

Of course I tried the Rich Snippets Tool which works perfectly for every pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked out your site and how the author pages are linked. The links look good. I did notice though that your profile picture is of you (I assume) but with a camera covering most of your face. In googles [page](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408986) about authorship links, it states you should have "a good, recognizable headshot as your profile photo". I don't know for sure, and like you said Google is full of mystery, but you could update your profile picture to be a full, normal headshot and see what happens.

Comment: Could be the case. I noticed some people using really random pictures though (drawing, logos...). But supposed I change my Google+ with my real picture, will they do something then? Do they have triggers on that kind of thing, with an human person (!) checking the new image (!) and activating the authorship links?

Comment: That is a very good question. I would hope there is some sort of automation for them determining who get's whitelisted (I haven't been whitelisted either, so I know how you're feeling), but I haven't seen anything from Google stating exactly how this process happens.

Comment: given that there are algorithms to recognize faces, I would guess they might have some script checking people's pictures to tell if there is a face in them or not. Either that or they have a lot of interns just checking if pictures contain human faces or not ;-)